# Incorrect Linking Under "History" Tab in Documentation Review Queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues

While going through the Documentation Review Queue, I discovered that clicking on the reviewed item link from the "*History*" tab located on the top right corner does not take the user back to the actual reviewed item; instead, it would take the user to the next review item in the queue.

Comment: Whoops!  Looking at that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix has been pushed out.

Thanks!